# PHP Windows, rmdir of a symlinked folder

Tags: php, windows, symlink, rmdir

I have recently been struggling with removal of symlinked folders with content on windows in PHP.

The process I am doing is:
1. symlink files/folders from location A to location B (all good)
2. unlink all files/folders from location B

Now this is where things get tricky. 
My code:

```
  echo("\n unlinking: ".$pre.$folder.'/'.$elem);
  if(file_exists($pre.$folder.'/'.$elem)){
        if(isWindows()){
            if(is_dir($pre.$folder.'/'.$elem)){
                rmdir($pre.$folder.'/'.$elem);
            } else {
                unlink($pre.$folder.'/'.$elem);
            }
        } else {
            unlink($pre.$folder.'/'.$elem);
        }
  } else {
    echo("\n -> Not there. \n");
  }
```

Everything works properly if the target is a file or an empty folder. When the symlinked folder has contents however, I get a warning that I can't remove a non-empty folder and the folder is not removed.

`Warning: rmdir(dirname): Directory not empty`

Which means that a symlinked folder with contents on windows is non-removable when using rmdir(the recommended operation).

I can remove that folder manually in windows explorer and that works properly(removes a symlink only).

Would appreciate help,
Sivael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was going on.

It turns out that it was not PHP related after all - those folders were under version control in TortoiseSVN and NetBeans, which happened to mess with the symlinks somehow.

Can't replicate the behaviour now.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

When deleting a symlink, you need to treat it as a file, not a directory. So, you need to use unlink, rather than rmdir!

HTH :)

Comment: On windows it is not so, unfortunately. On Linux it does work as You described.

Comment: Maybe something silly like it requires a slash at the end? Or not?

Comment: No, I've already posted the solution - the script is okay, it was a different problem - subversion contol over the files. Thank You for the help :)